# Parsing xml with php (create multidimensional array with for loop on elements of XML)

Tags: php, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array

i have a file.xml in folder... This file is:

```
<xml>
 <alert>
  <info>
   <area>
    <circle>18.980,153.480 0</circle>
   <area>
  </info>
  <info>
   <area>
    <circle>28.980,163.480 0</circle>
   <area>
  </info>
  <info>
   <area>
    <circle>38.980,173.480 0</circle>
   <area>
  </info>
 </alert>
```

i have an empty array and i want to creare a multidimensional array with numbers in element circle, so i must do a for loop for , but in my file xml i don't know how many info there are.

```
$url = "outvulcani/report.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$numinfo = substr_count($xml, "<info>");

for ($i = 0; $i <= $numinfo; $i++) {


$entry = $xml->alert->info[$i];
$coordinate = $entry->area->cirle;
$virgola = strpos($coordinate,",");
$spazio = strpos($coordinate," ");
$virg = $virgola;
$virgLng = $virgola+1;
$spaz = $spazio-$virgola;   
$lat = substr($coordinate,0,$virg);
$lng = substr($coordinate,$virgLng,$spaz);
$report[] = array($lat,$lng);

}
```

at the end i would like that the array **$report** is:

```
Array
(
      [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18.980
            [1] => 153.480 
        )

     [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28.980
            [1] => 163.480 
        )

     [2] => Array
       (
        [0] => 38.980
        [1] => 173.480 
      )

 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. That XML doesn't look valid though. The area tags need to be closed.

Test XML File

```
<alert>
  <info>
   <area>
    <circle>18.980,153.480 0</circle>
   </area>
  </info>
  <info>
   <area>
    <circle>28.980,163.480 0</circle>
   </area>
  </info>
  <info>
   <area>
    <circle>38.980,173.480 0</circle>
   </area>
  </info>
</alert>
```

Updated Script

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.xml');

$result = [];

foreach ($xml->info as $info) {
    $result[] = explode(',', $info->area->circle);
}

print_r($result);
```

Result

```
Array                        
(                            
    [0] => Array             
        (                    
            [0] => 18.980    
            [1] => 153.480 0 
        )                    

    [1] => Array             
        (                    
            [0] => 28.980    
            [1] => 163.480 0 
        )                    

    [2] => Array             
        (                    
            [0] => 38.980    
            [1] => 173.480 0 
        )                    

)
```

Comment: i put **foreach ($xml->alert->info as $info)**  but nothing the array is empty

Comment: but with your code works very good ! please, can you tell me why alert doesn'work ? :) thanks a lot Kelly !!

Comment: It depends on the contents of the xml file. Run a print_r($xml) after the call to simplexml_load_file and inspect the object it creates. That should give you an idea of how to access the nested elements.